# What does following statement mean: " Simulation was done at the rate of 12 samples per cycle of 50Hz a.c."

Tags: frequency, time-frequency

I am very new to the signal processing world and i am currently doing a project of studying frequency components in electrical machines. I am simulating the system in PSCAD. But i need to simulate the model at the rate of 12 samples per cycle of 50 Hz. What does that statement mean?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

One cycle duration of 50Hz is 0.02seconds. So this means you need to take 12 samples in a duration of 0.02s. In one second, there will be 600 samples (sample rate of 600 samples per second).

Answer (score 1):

"But i need to simulate the model at the rate of 12 samples per cycle of 50 Hz. What does that statement mean".

This is just another way of saying how often you would want to sample the underlying physical process. In this case every cycle of a 50Hz signal you are required to collect 12 samples. Something like the figure below:

[image]

So one period of 50Hz sinuoisd is 0.02s and in that 1 period you are collecting 12 samples, Therefore rate of sampling is $12*50$, 600Hz.

Important to keep in mind that the minimum rate required for sampling is 100Hz, i.e. twice the signal bandwidth